# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed, i dont know what to do

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this two tables in phpMyAdmin:

**ASSENZE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `assenze` (
    `idAssenza` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `ename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `starts` datetime NOT NULL,
    `ends` datetime NOT NULL
   )
```

**UTENTE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `utente` (
  `utenteID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `cognome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nomeUtente` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

I have to connect them throught Foreign Key which consist in putting "nomeUtente" in "assenze" table.

I tried with:

```
ALTER TABLE assenze
ADD COLUMN nomeUtente varchar(50),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (nomeUtente) REFERENCES utente(nomeUtente)
```

but it gives me this error ->

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

I also tried with add the column alone and that give it the FK attribute but doesnt work
On the internet i found other solution but didnt work for me. I dont know what to try anymore.

*P.S. i cannot delete the tables and redoit because they are connected to some php file and gives me error if i deleted and recreated*

---

I just wanted to add: thanks to everyone who's helping me

Comment: nomeUtente seems to be in the table assenze before you issue the alter table statement (according to what you have published) it also needs to be a key field see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html You should also include the table(s) engine and collation

Comment: `nomeUtente seems to be in the table assenze before you issue the alter table` 
what do you mean? i add nomeUtente when i alter the table, there isnt before that

Comment: `tables engine and collation` i dont know what are those and are they actually useful for my problem in adding the foreign key? I never need it before (just to be clear, this is not my first time trying to add FK, and in the past i did it right)

Comment: On your first comment sorry misread that, on your second comment 'Parent and child tables must use the same storage engine,' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html PS we can't know your previous mo..

Comment: no, i know that, i was just saying that before i never use `tables engine and collation` and worked as well

Comment: And eventually i just checked, and they both have `InnoDB` as engine, so they have the same one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every foeign ley needs an index on the column or columns referenced

So add a KEX to the nomeUtente

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `assenze` (
>     `idAssenza` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>     `ename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `starts` datetime NOT NULL,
>     `ends` datetime NOT NULL
>    )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `utente` (
>   `utenteID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>   `cognome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `nomeUtente` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
>   
> )
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE utente ADD
>   KEY(`nomeUtente`)
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE assenze
> ADD COLUMN nomeUtente varchar(50),
> ADD FOREIGN KEY (nomeUtente) REFERENCES utente(nomeUtente)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6abdd9ee6297ff08b0b28a5f8d1ab235)*

Comment: thanksss! I did it. @ChristianGiupponi gives me the right answer but was missing to add KEY attribute also in the utente table. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with your ALTER query you are trying to add another column with the same name `nomeUtente`

This:

```
ALTER TABLE assenze
ADD COLUMN nomeUtente varchar(50),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (nomeUtente) REFERENCES utente(nomeUtente)
```

Should be:

```
ALTER TABLE assenze
ADD FOREIGN KEY (nomeUtente) REFERENCES utente(nomeUtente)
```

Comment: I just try it and the sql console give me this error: La colonna chiave 'nomeUtente' non esiste nella tabella || Column key "nomeUtente" doesnt exist in the table

Comment: I just tried adding the column alone and did it, but dont know how to make it foreign :(